# Take a joystick or any changing/updating variable and bind/move a kivy slider?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I have a question for you all, is it possible to change a kivy slider's position on screen depending on some variables value? I want to change the slider's position based on a joysticks axis values. So for example:

if the joystick's axis value is a 1, I want the slider to move to the position corresponding to 1 and vice versa for -1.

The axis values are currently a Numeric Property, the Buttons are a Boolean Property, and the Hat switch is also a Numeric property

I've gotten the data to show up in a label fine, I am only wondering if this is possible.

Thanks in advance!

Edit with minimal reproducible code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.graphics.texture import Texture
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, NumericProperty, BooleanProperty, StringProperty

Builder.load_string("""
<ScreenOne>:
    GridLayout:
        rows: 1
        cols: 2
        Slider:
            id: J1Y
            min: -1
            max: 1
            step: 0.001
            orientation: 'vertical'
            value: root.Joy1X
        GridLayout:
            rows: 2
            cols: 1
            size_hint: 0.3, 1
            Button:
                text: "up"
                on_press: root.Up
            Button:
                text: "down"
                on_press: root.Down
""")

class ScreenOne(Screen):
    Joy1X = NumericProperty()

    def Up(self):
        self.Joy1X = self.Joy1X + 0.001

    def Down(self):
        self.Joy1X = self.Joy1X + 0.001

screen_manager = ScreenManager()

screen_manager.add_widget(ScreenOne(name="Control Screen"))

# Combine the Main Class above with the .kv file used for UI Graphics
class MainClass(App):
    def build(self):
        # self.load_kv('main.kv')
        return screen_manager

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainClass().run()
```

Comment: Yes, just set the `value` attribute of the `Slider` according to your variable.

Comment: I attempted that but the slider does not update its position, is there a way to get it to update? Thank you for the help ahead of time

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Updated per your request

Answer (score 0):

In your `kv`, the `on_press` attributes for your `Buttons` are incorrect. Almost everywhere else in python, references to method are specified without `()`, but in `kv` you need to include the `()`:

```
        Button:
            text: "up"
            on_press: root.Up()
        Button:
            text: "down"
            on_press: root.Down()
```